# Netsuite 2.0 Rest API Call giving error while fetching custom segment field

Tags: netsuite

I have developed Netsuite Rest API using 2.0 code and in GET method I am returning list of entities. This works ok if the list is not including a field which has custom segment tagged to it.

If I include this field i get below error in reponse

An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax: custentity..

I have given custom segment permission to the role. Does anyone have similar experience? What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an example of the code in question.  Specifically where the error is being returned from.

I have also seen some people say to change the visibility of the field(s) on the record, retest, then reset the display back to normal.

Also, just to clarify, you are not using nlobjectSearchColumn in 2.0, correct?  That is a 1.0 function, not a 2.0 function.  The 2.0 version is s.createColumn.